# I want to create a grid, but I'm not sure how to get it to display it correctly so that the grid includes "x" and doesn't look deformed

Tags: python

I'm a beginner to Python coding, and it's my first time asking a question here. So, I'm sorry if I make any mistakes in formatting this question.

As the title said, I am having trouble printing a grid so that it includes "x" while also ensuring that the grid stays in shape.

I have managed to create two versions of a code, one of which prints the grid in the desired shape, but does not include "x". The other one *does* include "x", but the grid is printed incorrectly.

Below is the one version of the code I have written:

```
from random import choice

grid_size = int(input("Enter grid size: "))
line = "-" * (7 + 6 * (grid_size-1))
main = []

def main_list():
    counter = grid_size
    while counter == grid_size or counter != 1:
        num(0)
        counter -= 1
    else:
        num(1)
        counter -= 1

def has_x():
    x = choice(range(len(main)))
    main[x] = "x"

def num(value):
    rand_num = choice(range(-30, 30))
    blank = " "
    main.append(rand_num)
    x = main[-1]

    if value == 0:
        if 0 <= x < 10:
            print("| ", x, end=blank*2)
        elif x >= 10 or -10 < x < 0:
            print("| ", x, end=blank)
        elif x <= -10:
            print("|", x, end=blank)
        elif x == 'x':
            print("|", 'x', end=blank)
    elif value == 1:
        if 0 <= x < 10:
            print("| ", x, end="  |\n")
        elif x >= 10 or -10 < x < 0:
            print("| ", x, end=" |\n")
        elif x <= -10:
            print("|", x, end=" |\n")
        elif x == 'x':
            print("|", 'x', end=" |\n")

def grid(grid_size):
    for i in range(grid_size):
        print(line)
        main_list()
    has_x()
    print(line)

grid(grid_size)
```

A sample output looks something like this:

```
>>> Enter grid size: 3
-------------------
| -14 |  -6 |  8  |
-------------------
| -24 | -24 |  26 |
-------------------
|  29 | -16 |  5  |
-------------------
```

The problem with this output is that since the numbers are being printed *before* has_x() is called, neither of the elements have been replaced with "x" yet, so it isn't displayed on the grid.

Another method I've tried is by making the following changes to main_list() and num():

```
def main_list():
    for i in range(grid_size):
        rand_num = choice(range(-30, 31))
        main.append(rand_num)

def num():
    for i in main:
        try:
            if 0 <= i < 10:
                print("| ", i, end="  ")
            elif i >= 10 or -10 < i < 0:
                print("| ", i, end=" ")
            elif i <= -10:
                print("|", i, end=" ")
        except:
            print("| ", "x", end="  ")
```

...and a sample output looks like this:

```
>>> Enter grid size: 3
-------------------
-------------------
-------------------
|  10 | -13 |  7  |  6  |  12 |  x  | -19 |  17 |  25 -------------------
```

Now, the "grid" properly displays "x", but its shape has been completely destroyed.

Is there a way for me to combine both of the codes I have written, so that has_x() is called before printing, and the grid is properly displayed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since replacing a number with an 'x' means you have to recalculate all the spacings, it's most convenient to just print the whole table again.

Here's my implementation of a generic function that prints a grid regardless of what's in it.

```
def print_grid(grid):
    # assume grid is a list of size n ** 2 for some n
    n = int(len(grid) ** 0.5)

    # convert all values to string
    grid = [str(value) for value in grid]

    # Spacing of each block equals
    # maximum length of a value inside a grid, plus 2 for margin
    spacing = max(map(len, grid)) + 2

    h_line = "-" * (spacing * n + n + 1)
    v_bar = "|"

    for i in range(n):
        print(h_line)

        print(v_bar, end="")
        for j in range(n):
            value = grid[i * n + j]

            # calculate so that the value appears in the middle
            remaining_space = spacing - len(value)
            left_margin = int(remaining_space / 2)
            right_margin = remaining_space - left_margin

            print(" " * left_margin + value + " " * right_margin + v_bar, end="")
        print()
        
    print(h_line)
```

The rest should be simple. First fill a grid and print it out, then replace one block with an "x", then print it out again.

```
def main():
    # you may let user choose this value
    size = 5
    grid_size = size ** 2

    # you may replace range with a randomizing function
    grid = list(range(grid_size))
    print_grid(grid)

    # change one of grid's blocks to an 'x'
    # again, you may replace this with a randomizer
    grid[-1] = "x"

    # print it again
    print_grid(grid)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```